# Не регулируется высота Toast для приложения под андроид

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день!

Я создала Toast и вставила туда картинку (через LinearLayout). Но почему-то после добавления картинки Toast растянуло по вертикали по максимуму. Некрасиво. :( Параметра, устанавливающего максимальную высоту, не нашла. Как быть?

Спасибо за ответ.

Код создания Toast:

```
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.short_toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            LinearLayout ShortToastContainer = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
            ImageView ShortToastImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            ShortToastImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.message);
            ShortToastContainer.addView(ShortToastImageView, 0);
            toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, этого сделать нельзя. И причины вроде как очевидны - тостом можно будет показывать, например, рекламу поверх всех приложений и еще много чего.

Но существуют [библиотеки](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+toast), позволяющие показывать подобие тоста, полностью кастомизируемое.

Вообще тост категорически не предназначен для того, чтобы пихать в него картинки (максимум, возможно, иконку?). Напишите, зачем вы хотите это сделать, и я уверен, вам предложат более правильное решение...

Comment: Идея была в том, чтобы показывать раз в сутки при открытом окне определенное сообщение. Уровень у меня чуть превышает "Hello, world!". Поэтому под свои идеи ищу уроки и делаю по ним. Картинка изначально была не нужна, но делала по уроку http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/toast.php и девочковая натура взяла верх и захотелось "посимпатичнее". А у автора урока Toast не расплывается по экрану.

Comment: если вам нужно показывать что-либо, пока ваше приложение на экране, то лучше используйте, например, PopupWindow

Comment: Нет, дело именно в том, что необходимо показывать сообщение вне зависимости, оно на экране или его там нет...

Comment: @Alemarika, я думаюю, что пользователи мягко говоря будут нерады тому, что ваши тосты закрывают контент на экране. Это плохо.

Comment: Добавляйте сообщение в область уведомлений

Answer (score 0):

Ну... Попробуйте высоту вручную задать:

```
LinearLayout ShortToastContainer = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) ShortToastContainer.getLayoutParams();
params.height=LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;//или число в пикселях. 100, например
ShortToastContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
```

И таки не надо переменные с заглавной буквы писать. Принято их с маленькой, а название класса - с большой.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока не работает, вылетает со словами: "К сожалению, ваше приложение остановлено", буду вечером копаться в логах.

По поводу оформления Вы несомненно правы. Может, посоветуете ресурс, где есть коротко про правильное оформление? Буду весьма благодарна.